# Get correct width of a textBlock in WinForm

Tags: wpf, winforms, label, size, textblock

I have a WPF control that creates dynamic some textBlocks and increase the font size until the textBlocks have a maximum font size in order to fit in the parent.

I am using the following method in order to get the size of a textBlock with a specific fontSize:

```
 private Size MeasureTextBlockSize(TextBlock textBlock)
    {
        // Measured Size is bounded to be less than maxSize
        Size maxSize = new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity);
        textBlock.Measure(maxSize);
        return textBlock.DesiredSize;
    }
```

In WPF everything works perfectly, but when i am using the control in a WinForm application, the text will be bigger than its parent. This means the method doesn't work correctly.

I tried the same approach with Labels but with the same result.

Do you have any idea why this happens or how can i fix it?

To understand better my problem i will attach some images from WPF and from WinForm:

This is WPF:

[image]

And this is WinForm:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Graphics object to measure the string using `MeasureString()` method:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string testStr = "0#2" + Environment.NewLine
        + "1400" + Environment.NewLine
        + "800";

   var rows = testStr.Split('\n');
    // use graphics object to measure the string using MeasureString() method
    Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();

    foreach (var row in rows)
    {
        var strSize = g.MeasureString(row, label1.Font);
        Debug.WriteLine("text: {0} width: {1} height: {2}",row, strSize.Width.ToString(),strSize.Height.ToString());
    }

}
```

**OUTPUT:**

> text: 0#2  width: 22.56396 height: 13.82519
>  text: 1400  width:
>   28.86426 height: 13.82519
>  text: 800 width: 22.56754 height: 13.82519

Comment: And what is different from my method?

Comment: Also don't forget i use a WPF control. the label doesn't contains a Font property.

Comment: I will be able to share with you my improved suggeation when i will be near my pc